# Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Assume A and B are two independent random variables with known distributions (say Normal). I am interested in simplifying the following probability into a closed form formula.

$$Pr(A \lt 0 | A+B \geq 0)$$

I tried $P(a|b)=\frac{P(a \cap b)}{P(b)}$ and some other probability rules but could not achieve a nice closed form.

Comment: Hint: If A + B > 0, and A < 0, what does that tell you about B's relationship to A? Also, does closed form formula mean you want to write this in terms of the pdfs of A and B?

Comment: @ilanman Thanks for editing my post. Yes I want to write this in terms of the pdfs of A and B.

Comment: @ilanman if A+B>0 and A<0 then B should be positive and B>-A. But how would it be helpful?

Comment: Have you tried writing out $P(A \le 0 \cap A+B \geq 0) = \int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{-a}^{\infty} f(a,b)dadb$ ? You said that the pdfs are known and independent.

Comment: @ilanman You just blew my mind! Since A and B are independent f(a,b)=f(a)f(b). Now, can I say $\int_{-∞}^0\int_{-a}^∞f(a,b)dadb=\int_{-∞}^0f(a)\int_{-a}^∞f(b)dbda$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of providing an answer full of hints (assuming this is self-study), more formally than in the comments:

Hint 1: Write out

$$P(A < 0 |A+B \geq 0) = \frac{P(A<0,A+B \geq 0)}{P(A+B \geq 0 )}$$

Hint 2: Let $C = A+B$. Given densities $f_A(a)$ and $f_B(b)$, we can write the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions):

$$P(A + B < c) = F_{A+B}(c) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_A(c-b)f_B(b)db$$

This is using the fact that $A$ and $B$ are independent. This approach is analogous for discrete RVs (except using summations). Since you want densities only, we can differentiate the above with respect to $c$:

$$p_{A+B}(c) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_A(c-b)f_B(b)db$$

Hint 3: If you know the distributions of your RVs, then your life can be made much easier using [generating functions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)